# Apache CXF Spring rest service POST request returns "msg" : "Stream closed"

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl, cxf

I work with an Apache Cxf, Spring Jax-rs service and I have the following service definition and the implementations provided,

THE DEFINITION

```
    @POST
    @Path("/generateAddress")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    WalletInfo generateAddress(final String walletName, String currencyName);
```

THE IMPLEMENTATIONS

```
public synchronized WalletInfo generateAddress(final String walletName, String currencyName) {

        WalletInfo walletInfo = IWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);
        return walletInfo;
}
```

When I do the `POST` request with the `cURL` like
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"walletName":"Icecream5500","currencyName":"Bitcoin"}' http://localhost:8080/api/rest/wallet/generateAddress`

I get the `JSON` response back,

```
{
  "msg" : "Stream closed",
  "date" : "2017-08-28T09:22:027Z"
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the `generateAddress` method works fine. What is
the issue here and particularly, when you would get the message `Stream closed` in the Spring Apache Cxf project while doing the `POST` requests? Obviously, I can provide more info if required. The server log is normal and I see nothing unusual.

Comment: In what scenario are you getting the message `Stream closed` ?

Comment: I get the message while doing the post request using the cURL. I have provided the detailed info. You may read the question again.

Comment: Ohh my bad. I thought the actual response was Stream closed in place of JSON. Are you debugging the code while executing this request?

Comment: I'm not doing so

Comment: curl contains `'{"walletName":"Icecream5500","currencyName":"Bitcoin"}'` as the body of the request. But generateAddress has two parameters. How will the body map to any of the method parameter?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I provided an answer of how I have solved the issue and you may have a look there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `POST` body doesn't match with the parameters of the method and this created the issue in the first place. I have solved the problem in the following options.

I created a new class

```
public class CreateWalletWithNameAndCurrency {

    String walletName;

    String currencyName;

    public CreateWalletWithNameAndCurrency(String walletName, String currencyName) {
        this.walletName = walletName;
        this.currencyName = currencyName;
    }

    public CreateWalletWithNameAndCurrency() {
    }

    public String getWalletName() {
        return walletName;
    }

    public String getCurrencyName() {
        return currencyName;
    }

    public void setCurrencyName(String currencyName) {
        this.currencyName = currencyName;
    }

    public void setWalletName(String walletName) {
        this.walletName = walletName;
    }
}
```

I changed the definition of the `POST` request like this,

```
@POST
@Path("generateAddress")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
WalletInfo generateAddress(CreateWalletWithNameAndCurrency createWalletWithNameAndCurrency);
```

The implementation is provided below,

```
public synchronized WalletInfo generateAddress(CreateWalletWithNameAndCurrency createWalletWithNameAndCurrency) {

        String walletName = createWalletWithNameAndCurrency.getWalletName();

        String currencyName = createWalletWithNameAndCurrency.getCurrencyName();

        WalletInfo walletInfo = iWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);


    // some more code 
}
```

Finally, I can do the `POST` request like this,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"walletName":"Copenhangen","currencyName":"Bitcoin"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/wallet/generateAddress
```